# GNU Health - Timezone Errors

Tags: python, timezone, gnu, pytz

After a few days of search and trying to use pytz and other tools, I am unable to find a solution.

When a user creates a Medication print-out list in GNU Health an error is given:

```
====== ERROR=======================                 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/trytond/protocols/jsonrpc.py", line 150, in _marshaled_dispatch
 response['result'] = dispatch_method(method, params)
 File "/trytond/protocols/jsonrpc.py", line 179, in _dispatch
res = dispatch(*args)
File "/trytond/protocols/dispatcher.py", line 161, in dispatch
result = rpc.result(meth(*c_args, **c_kwargs))
 File "/trytond/report/report.py", line 144, in execute
type, data = cls.parse(action_report, records, data, {})
File "/trytond/modules/health/report/health_report.py", line 62, in            parse
localcontext['print_date'] = get_print_date()
File "/trytond/modules/health/report/health_report.py", line 42, in get_print_date
return datetime.astimezone((dt.replace(tzinfo=None))
TypeError: astimezone() argument 1 must be datetime.tzinfo, not None                  
============END=================
```

I am not sure how to rectify this issue

Comment: what is `datetime.astimezone((dt.replace(tzinfo=None))` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I would understand if it were to raise: `ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime` then it it would be equivalent to
`dt.replace(tzinfo=None).astimezone()` but `TypeError` suggests  `datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone(tz=None)`like code (before Python 3.3+
where empty argument is interperted as a local timezone:
[`.astimezone(tz)`: *Changed in version 3.3: tz now can be omitted*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone). Anyway, it is a bad style to use `klass.method(obj, *args)`
instead of `obj.method(*args)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [the current code for `get_print_date()`](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/health/file/cd2e0a905425/tryton/health/report/health_report.py):

```
def get_print_date():
    Company = Pool().get('company.company')

    timezone = None
    company_id = Transaction().context.get('company')
    if company_id:
        company = Company(company_id)
        if company.timezone:
            timezone = pytz.timezone(company.timezone)

    dt = datetime.now()
    return datetime.astimezone(dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc), timezone)
```

It seems it tries (incorrectly unless `TZ=UTC` -- you should submit a bug report) to do the following:

```
import tzlocal # $ pip install tzlocal

def get_print_date():
    Company = Pool().get('company.company')
    company_id = Transaction().context.get('company')
    company = company_id and Company(company_id)
    timezone = company and company.timezone and pytz.timezone(company.timezone)
    return datetime.now(timezone or tzlocal.get_localzone())
```

i.e., it either returns the current time in the `company`'s timezone or in your local timezone.

Comment: This makes sense, I could not follow what was happening at all in the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up your institution / company timezone ?

You can check / set  your company timezone in  Party -> Configuration -> Companies -> Timezone